# Does HTML 5 video ogg and mpg allow linking to web sites?

Tags: flash, html

Ok so I know when I create a Flash file I can utilize ActionScript to link buttons created in the .swf video file. Can I do the same with HTML 5? I would like to change one of my swf files over to HTML 5 to experiment with the new code. I heard Flash was going to offer this feature in CS5. I have CS5 anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Do you have your swf somewhere online? I'm guessing it would be possible (albeit difficult) to do in html5 + js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, not in the least. Video is completely different from interactivity. By detecting the position on the timeline, however, you can display annotations.

You must understand that SWF files are executable. MP4 files are not.

In CS5, you have to export as an HTML page with HTML5 rather than SWF content. I hope this makes sense.